# What is the disk size limit for mdadm?

Tags: raid, disk, mdadm, software-raid

> What, if any, is the disk size limit for mdadm?

I've been using mdadm to manage disk arrays for our Mac network for a number of years now.  Our storage requirements have grown to the point I'm considering using 4TB or 8TB disks.  Is mdadm known to work with these, and if so, what is its limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `mdadm` is known to work with 4TB and 8TB disks. Its limits (with superblock format 1.0) [are as follows](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats):

- up to at least 384 component devices (256 in RAID6);
- component devices with up to 2<sup>64</sup> 512-byte sectors, *i.e.* 8 ZiB.

So you’ve still got lots of breathing space.

Comment: I'm slightly amused that there will in the not too distant future, be a time when your "8 Zibibytes is lots of breathing space" will no longer hold true!

Comment: Doesn't seems to work that well : I have been blocked trying to ga above 16TiB